# Code::Blocks stopped working suddenly and doesn't open any more

Tags: codeblocks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs0DA.png)

Tried installing and re-installing but of no use.
Every time it says Keyboard Shortcut Conflict for Ctrl+P. But I can't do anything about it as it doesn't open up. I do have keybinder but I don't know how to sort this out.

Inserted Screenshot of exact error message showed. I even tried installing nightly builds but the same error message pops up. every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the user files (only the "keybinding" files) in the directory below then restating CodeBlocks will help if the problem is just because a key conflict:

directory: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks\`

Depending on the CodeBlocks version, the file names may be something like; `cbKeyBinder10.ini`, `default.cbKeyBinder10.ini`, `default.cbKeyBinder20.conf`

**Important note**: To be on the safe side, instead of deleting those files immediately, just rename their extensions as `.ini_bak` or `.conf_bak`. If this procedure solves your problem, you can, then, delete the backup files. If not, you can rollback your changes by returning the extensions back to their originals.